# JComboBox changes components only when going from 1st to 2nd (Not from 3rd to 2nd)

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

So I tried searching for a solution but found nothing and didn't know how to make my search more accurate.
I have this for homework in Java and I got stuck with a `JComboBox` that doesn't always change the components in my `JPanel`.
This is my first time posting a question so sorry if I mess up with this.
Anyhow, this is the code (The purpose is to create GUI for a flight company).

The problem is that when I go from option 1("office") to option 2("Pilot"), the `JComboBox` does what it should do and changes the `JPanel` (jplType) as should, but when I go from option 3("Host") back to option 2, it doesn't change the `JPanel` (jplType) at all.

The thing is, I put a `System.out.println()` in the

```
if(index == 1)
{
  // ..
}
```

and it does print it but for some reason it fails to add the `JCheckBox`.

I'd be grateful if someone can figure out what I messed up here because I've been at it for an hour.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class abc {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompanyDialog abc = new CompanyDialog();

    }

}

class CompanyDialog extends JFrame {

    private String[] employee = {"office", "Pilot", "Host"};
    private String[] employeeTitles = {"Office options", "Pilot options", "Host options"};
    public final static int GAP = 3;
    // Frame Constants.
    public final static int FWIDTH = 605;
    public final static int FHEIGHT = 235;
    // Constant for the Combo Box.
    public final static int CBWIDTH = FWIDTH/3-4;
    public final static int CBHEIGHT = 20;
    // Width constant for TextField.
    public final static int TWIDTH = 20;

    private JPanel jplType = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, GAP, GAP));

    private JComboBox jcbType = new JComboBox(employee);
    private JLabel jlblOptions = new JLabel();
    private JTextField jtfOptions = new JTextField(TWIDTH);

public CompanyDialog(){
    super("Worker Dialog");

    //Combo box panel configurations
    JPanel jplWorker = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, GAP, GAP));

    JTextField nametxt = new JTextField(TWIDTH);
    jcbType.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CBWIDTH,CBHEIGHT));
    jplWorker.add(jcbType);

    setDisplay(0);

    add(jplWorker, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(FWIDTH, FHEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);

    jcbType.addItemListener(new ItemListener() { /**Handle item selection*/
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            jplType.removeAll();
            setDisplay(jcbType.getSelectedIndex());
        }
    }
            );
}
public void setDisplay(int index){
    jplType.add(jlblOptions);
    jplType.add(jtfOptions);
    jplType.setBorder(new TitledBorder(employeeTitles[index]));
    if(index == 0){
        jlblOptions.setText("Office:");
        jtfOptions.setText("");
    }
    else if(index == 1) {
        jlblOptions.setText("Air Time:");
        jtfOptions.setText("0");
        JCheckBox jcbCaptain = new JCheckBox("Is a Captain");
        jplType.add(jcbCaptain);
    }
    else if(index == 2){
        jlblOptions.setText("Air Time:");
        jtfOptions.setText("0");
    }

    add(jplType, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: Minimized it now I think, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your setDisplay() Method from

```
public void setDisplay(int index){
        jplType.add(jlblOptions);
        jplType.add(jtfOptions);
        jplType.setBorder(new TitledBorder(employeeTitles[index]));
        if(index == 0){
            jlblOptions.setText("Office:");
            jtfOptions.setText("");
        }
        else if(index == 1) {
            jlblOptions.setText("Air Time:");
            jtfOptions.setText("0");
            JCheckBox jcbCaptain = new JCheckBox("Is a Captain");
            jplType.add(jcbCaptain);
        }
        else if(index == 2){
            jlblOptions.setText("Air Time:");
            jtfOptions.setText("0");
        } 
        else
        {
            jlblOptions.setText("");
            jtfOptions.setText("");
        }
        add(jplType, BorderLayout.CENTER);

     }
```

to

```
public void setDisplay(int index){
        jplType.add(jlblOptions);
        jplType.add(jtfOptions);
        jplType.setBorder(new TitledBorder(employeeTitles[index]));
        if(index == 0){
            jlblOptions.setText("Office:");
            jtfOptions.setText("");
        }
        else if(index == 1) {
            jlblOptions.setText("Air Time:");
            jtfOptions.setText("0");
            JCheckBox jcbCaptain = new JCheckBox("Is a Captain");
            jplType.add(jcbCaptain);
        }
        else if(index == 2){
            jlblOptions.setText("Air Time:");
            jtfOptions.setText("0");
        } 
        else
        {
            jlblOptions.setText("");
            jtfOptions.setText("");
        }
        add(jplType, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.revalidate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private JPanel jplType = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, GAP, GAP));
    ////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////
    public void setDisplay(int index){
       jplType.add(jlblOptions);
       jplType.add(jtfOptions);
       jplType.setBorder(new TitledBorder(employeeTitles[index]));
       if(index == 0){
           jlblOptions.setText("Office:");
           jtfOptions.setText("");
       }
       else if(index == 1) {
           jlblOptions.setText("Air Time :");
           jtfOptions.setText("0");
           JCheckBox jcbCaptain = new JCheckBox("Is a Captain");
           jplType.add(jcbCaptain);
       }
       else if(index == 2){
           jlblOptions.setText("Air Time :");
           jtfOptions.setText("0");
       }
       add(jplType, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
       // 
       //
       revalidate();
       repaint(); 
       //
   }
```

bad idea to expect that Layout will arrange his content on his own, and especially when you use such simple Layout as FlowLayout

Comment: What do you mean to expect FlowLayout to arrange the layout on it's own? FlowLayout arranges the layout based on the order you add, no?

Comment: in (index == 1) you add the same object in the same sequence as in (index == 2), that perfectly fit in in some sort of Map Of The Object that remain from (index == 2), to get automatic revalidation there should be some error at the begining of the Map,  try without (revalidation()) by simply chenging text in ( jlblOptions.setText("Air Time :"); ), it will work

Comment: Ah, I already fixed that about 5 minutes ago, I just split the else if(index == 1) into an else that adds these 2 components and then the ifs inside it that will add what ever each of them is supposed to.